# Python parse multiline shell commands?

Tags: python, shell, command-line, shlex

Python provides the library `shlex` to parse shell commands. This appears not to parse multiline strings.

The shell command

```
python3 \
arg
```

is equivalent to `subproces.check_call(["python3", "arg"])`

However, `shlex.split` appends to append a newline to the argument.

```
>>> shlex.split("python3 \\\narg")
['python3', '\narg']
```

Is there an idiomatic way to parse multiline shell commands.

## Approaches tried

[bashlex](https://github.com/idank/bashlex) is a more general version of `shlex`. It does a slightly better job.

```
>>> list(bashlex.split("python3 \\\narg"))
['python3', '\n', 'arg']
```

Comment: What is the expected output? For input, I see a command name `python3` with a 4-character argument consisting of a linefeed, an `a`, and `r`, and a `g`, so `shlex.split` is parsing it correctly.

Comment: You can specify multiline arguments enclosed in quotes.

Comment: @chepner I've added more context above. I want `subproces.check_call(shlex.split(x))` to do the same thing as bash would.

Comment: `shlex` is for *lexical* analysis, not full-blown parsing. If you can't get an appropriate command list in the first place, just use `shell=True` instead.

Comment: A question isn't wrong just because you can't instantly answer it chepner! I am happy to use another tool, I would prefer to reuse code if it exists. I want to parse the command and understand it's meaning, not execute it.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there an idiomatic way

No.

> Python parse multiline shell commands?

Regex replace a slash followed a newline for a whitespace. Something along `re.sub(r"\\\n", r" ", ...` or similar.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I tried. But I was hoping there was a library that could magically do it wo something. Unfortunately I then had problems with c-style strings (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/155367/when-to-use-bash-ansi-c-style-escape-e-g-n), so had to use a completely different approach to the problems.